# Rails 3 + Devise: How do I change other user's passwords from an admin role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

I've developed a Rails 3 application with Devise for registration and login control. I want to be able to modify any user's password to one I provide.
The solution I've come up with (I haven't had the chance to test it yet) is to make a fake new registration with the password I choose, copy the password from the table record to the user's record in question, and then delete the fake record I generated in the DB. It's not the most elegant thing to do, but it is all I've got. I wait for better suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I might be misunderstanding the question but it should be as simple as;

```
@user = User.find(<some id>)
@user.update_attributes(:password => 'anewpassword', :password_confirmation => 'anewpassword')
```

then their password will be 'anewpassword'

Comment: The thing is that Devise stores the password in an "encrypted_password" field (I think it uses MD5 or similar) and a password such as "qweqwe" becomes "$2a$10$TqfBNCfMx3NfDoLFPVKtSuEKmxLkhQsrLSwLI6dSuGCHNkmO3Ggfm". That's why I can't store the password directly like that.

Comment: you never want to store an unencrypted password...ever!